# Vue cli run production build on VPS server after closing console

Tags: vue.js, pm2, vue-cli, serve

My VPS server is all set. Node is installed, I built an app and ran it with

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s dist
```

as it was mentioned in the docs.

But after I close my console the application is not available anymore. I'm aware about PM2, but I couldnt run

```
serve -s dist
```

with it.

I would appreciate the ideas on easy way to always serve the application on server
Thanx

Comment: Add an `&` after the command to send the process to the background.

Comment: Just tried
After I close console app is unavailable anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling quite a while with nginx i finally managed to set it up properly. So as far as I understand, the only solution is to install a web-server, such as Nginx